# Label not centered after data change in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application I have Label:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalTextAlignment ="Center">
```

In ViewModel:

```cs
private int _number;
public int Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _number, value); }
}
```

When message is received, I update number:

```cs
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<EmptyMessage>(this, "NUMBER_CHANGED", OnNumberChanged);

private async void OnNumberChanged(EmptyMessage emptyMessage)
{
    Number = ReadNumberFromDB();
}
```

All of this is on MainPage. When "NUMBER_CHANGED" message is triggered from MainPage, Number is updated on UI and **label containing Number is properly centered**.

From MainPage, one can PushAsync SecondPage. From SecondPage "NUMBER_CHANGED" can also be triggered. After triggering it and returning to MainPage, Number is updated, **label containing it has proper value but instead of being centered it is left aligned**.

Is this Xamarin UI bug? Is there a workaround for this? I need somehow to tell label to refresh it's position. I want label to always be centered. I don't know why it is left aligned after refreshing it's content.

Comment: if you add `XAlign = "Center"` in XAML, does that make any difference?

Comment: You may want to wrap your label inside a STACKLAYOUT where you FORCE it to be centered through your app width, instead of trying to align the individual label

Comment: Is this on Android specifically because I have found on many occasions HorizontalText/VerticalTextAlignment don't always behave correctly on things that dynamically update. I have also noticed this issue seems a bit worse with Forms 2.3.4 so most of the time I've just switched to Horizontal/VerticalOptions even though they're slightly more performance intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HorizontalTextAlignment and VerticalTextAlignment, not working after a data change is a known bug. [Bug 55359](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=55359) details this for a TabbedPage, but it occurs in many places, such as [Bug 49311](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=49311).

The workaround is to use HorizontalOptions or VerticalOptions for the moment.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem recently. I simply made a constant variable to track what page needed to be updated OnResume and just reassigned my bindings accordingly.